# If $g(x+h) = f(x)$, do I know $g(x) = f(x - h)$?

Tags: functions

I'm not sure how the rules to this work:

Find $g(x)$ if $g(x + h) = f(x)$. Can I just move the $h$ over as if it was a normal equation so that $g(x) = f(x - h)$? Setting $x + h = x$ doesn't really make much sense, since something like $x + 4 = x$ would just evaluate to $4 = 0$. If I can, how do I show mathematically that I can just subtract $h$ over to the other side?

Comment: It depends. If you mean that $x$ is a free variable and that $g(x+h) = f(x)$ holds for all $x$ then yes. If $x$ is fixed then in general no: $g(10+h) = f(10)$ does not say anything about $g(10)$ being equal to $f(10-h)$. In this context the question is most likely to be read "Find the function $g(x)$ given that $g(x+h) = f(x)$ for all $x$" so the answer is yes.

Comment: @Winther  That is a really good point! Then the functions could simply intersect at that point but be completely different otherwise.

Comment: @name Though it is worth noting that by convention, $x$ is used as a free variable in functions - at least I've never seen an instance where it was intended as a fixed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you do:

$g(x+h) = f(x)$

Let $t= x-h$, then:

$g(t+h) = f(t) \implies g(x-h+h)=f(x-h)\implies g(x)=f(x-h)$

Note the functions hold for an any  inputs (which we arbitrarily call $x$) in the intersections of their domains. So it must then hold for an arbitrary variable $t=x-h$ for all $t$ in the domain of the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to solve this kind of question you've got to think - what do these symbols really mean?

The equality
$$g(x+h) = f(x)$$
says that if we evaluate $f$ at $x$, then we get the same result as evaluating $g$ at $x+h$. The point $x$ is an arbitrary choice (i.e it doesn't matter), therefore if we evaluate $f$ at $x-h$ it is the same as evaluating $g$ at $x-h + h = x$. So yes, we do have that

$$ g(x)=f(x-h).$$